# Overriding the look of a single character?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I want to override the look of the letter I in mathsf's font as it looks like a vertical bar and the letter l. By default, it looks like the following:

[image]

My goal is to have look like that:

[image: Desired output]

How can I change this single letter in mathsf's font only?

I have looked at [How do I change the font of a letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/how-do-i-change-the-font-of-a-letter) and [Changing one letter changes that letter throughout a paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418983/changing-one-letter-changes-that-letter-throughout-a-paper) but they didn't help me very much. I even used [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) but it didn't help either.

**Edit:**

With the help of [@David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523642/167081)'s answer, I came up with a semi-solution by declaring a new command called `\I` and assigned it the following:

```
\newcommand{\I}{{\fontfamily{lcmss}\selectfont\ensuremath{\mathrm{I}}}}
```

So that `$\I$, \I` gives:

[image: Output]

Comment: You could search for an I that matches your needs in other fonts, make I math-active and have it switch the font family and input an I from that family.

Comment: @Skillmon, Can you please direct me to place showing how to do all of this? I am not comfortable with changing fonts like that. I want to make sure I do it properly.

Comment: @M.AlJumaily I have no idea how to do it properly :) I'm not good with fonts, too. But I did something like that once. My solution didn't cover shape or series changes though, just so you're warned. The first step you have to do is find a font that contains the letter you want to use. If you got that, you have to make it available with `\DeclareSymbolFont` and then you can use `\DeclareMathSymbol` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2972/117050 for a rough idea).

Comment: @Skillmon, thanks for the honesty and the reference :).

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far? Do you have a font you want to use? Do you know `arevmath`? It's a package that defines an sans-serif math alphabet with unambiguous letters. Maybe you want to ditch `sfmath` and use `arevmath` instead. Or do you need a very specific font?

Comment: My thought was to use Ti*k*Z to draw the desired I. Then, I would only change the I in the mathsf font. That's all. I don't want to change it globally in all fonts, only in that specific font. Once, I have the approach, I can then simply draw the Ti*k*Z diagram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LaTeX includes a modified sans serif font `lcmss` derived from cmss but with adjustments to make more characters distinguishable, including the capital i.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathsf{OT1}{lcmss}{m}{n}

\begin{document}


$ 1+2 +3 + \mathsf{IJK} + \mathsf{ijk} $

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to only change the letter I and keep the everything else untouched?

Comment: Ow, I never heard about `lcmss`. Nice.

Comment: @Sigur slides class (people lured to beamer but slides still has some hidden tricks:-)

Comment: @M.AlJumaily in theory yes but it's considerably more complicated and fragile. Also it would be a completely different answer. The point of this answer is rather to suggest using a different font rather than patching individual letters. So someone else will no doubt post a different technique, if you accept that answer that's fine, but I don't want to change the message of this one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the other answer (changing only a single glyph/letter) would be a duplicate from the ones linked in the OP.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to find a semi solution that I attached in the question.

Answer (score 1):

With the `unicode-math` package, you can override a single math-mode character with the `[range=...]` option of `\setmathfont`, in this case, `\setmathfont[range=\msansI]` to change only the mathematical sans-serif I.  You might, however, have better results loading an entire sans-serif alphabet as `\setmathfont[range=sfup]`.

With legacy fonts, you can load a `\mathsf` alphabet with the `[sfdefault=...]` option of [the `isomath` package.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/isomath/isomath.pdf)  The supported options in OML encoding are `cmbr`, `fav`, `hvm`, `iwona`, `jkpfss` and `llcmss`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to descend to some low-level TeX to make this work. The command you care about is `\mathcode` which is described in chapter 17 of *The TeXbook*. I don't have my copy handy to give you a complete accounting of what you need to do, but you'll do something along the lines of

```
\mathcode`I="7A49
```

where the `A` is going to need to be changed to correspond to the numeric value for the math font family—it will be a value somewhere in the range 8–F depending on when the alphabet gets declared.

I hope this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Can I confirm that this will change a specific letter only when using the mathsf font?

Comment: This is equivalent to doing `\DeclareMathSymbol`, so you won't need some low-level TeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2970/117050 (as linked in the OP).

Comment: @M.AlJumaily the 7 at the start means that it will be affected by math alphabet commands (e.g. `\mathbf`).

Comment: Note that in latex  math alphabets like `\mathsf` are allocated on demand when (if) first used so the hex digit you need to use in the `\mathcode` to represent the math font family depends on the specific document and the order that `\mathsf`, `\mathfrak` etc are used.